# Creating a texture image from existing image

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I have some unusual question. I have searched online and couldn't find something similar to what I want to achieve.

I have an image, and I want to create a new image from it (in the same size), so the value of each pixel in the new image will be an indication for the texture of the pixel's close environment. By that I mean that, for example, parts with diffrenet textures from nearby parts will get diffrent values.

I know that segmentation exists but I don't want to partition the image into segments; I just want a way to tell how much each pixel is in an area that its texture is "diffrent" and by how much.

I tried using Matlab's *stdfilt* and *rangefilt* (I have rewritten them in OpenCV, C++), but they are no good: I tried using them with a lot of diffrenet parameters, but diffrenet textures get too close values, so my seperation is not good.

I know this question is a bit ambiguous but I just want to know which methods can I use (in openCV) to give me the result I want.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about Textures in OpenGL? Can you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: This kind of texture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_texture